# Open Excelworkbook with userform - based on Alphabet. Can it be done?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering if it is possible to:

1. make a userform in, for example, "Workbook1"
2. have an excelworkbook that stores playerinformation. But make an excel workbook for every leter in the alphabet. ( so Names that
   start with A will come in "workbook A"
3. Write away data from the userform to the specific workbook when choosing a letter from the alphabet.

So my userform would have:

1. a box where you can shoose the letter of the alphabet the name starts with
2. a textbox to put in the playername
3. other boxes to put in some additional information that has to be written away

An additional question. Can I do the opposit? So for example when I give the letter A in the userform. Can I get stats out of another workbook based on the name I give in?

a box where you can shoose the letter of the alphabet the name starts with

Comment: Can it be done? Yes. Should it be done? No. Opening and closing 26 workbooks to mimic a database is just plain wrong on a large number of levels.

Comment: I suggest using ADODB objects. You're better off building a database (Access for instance) rather than storing your data in workbooks (You can still use ADODB with Excel workbooks).

Answer (score 0):

This is sub for you. Add other controls by you.

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
       Dim sh As String
        sh = Left(Me.ComboBox1.Value, 1)
       Sheets(sh).Activate
    End Sub
```